# 100% height dependent on height of brother element

Tags: html, css

I need the element *cnt-right* to be height 100% of its sibling.

It doesn't have a parent element, only siblings.

Is it possible to accomplish this with CSS? Or do I have to use javascript?

I have this estructure: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h7s590az/259/)
[image]

```css
.column {
  display: block;
  min-height: 50px;
  background-color: #ccc;  
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

.decktop-12 {
  width: 100%;
}

.decktop-8 {
  width: 66%;
}

.decktop-4 {
  width: 33%;
}

.cnt {
  background-color: #995595;
}

.cnt-right {
  background-color: #559959;
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile-12 decktop-12 cnt-top column">
  Content top
</div>
<div class="mobile-12 decktop-8 cnt column">
  Content - main
  <br /> <br />
  Content - main
  <br /> <br />
  Content - main
  <br /> <br />
  Content - main
  <br /> <br />
  Content - main
</div>
<div class="mobile-12 decktop-4 cnt-right column">
  Content - right
</div>
<div class="mobile-12 decktop-12 cnt-bottom column">
  Content bottom
</div>
```

Comment: You can use display:flex for this; example: https://jsfiddle.net/fv7gja5b/

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but the elements are sibling. Its not have element parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use css grid or flex displays.

I recommand you to have a look at :

- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/
- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox

And also at how Bootstrap 4 implemented their grid using flex :
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

You will have more control over how your grid behaves and possibilities than with float.

I made you an example with using flex. In this example flex evens the columns height by default and looks similar to code written with float :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="mobile-12 desktop-12 column c1">
        Content top
    </div>
    <div class="mobile-12 desktop-8 column c2">
        Content - main
        <br><br><br>
    </div>
    <div class="mobile-12 desktop-4 column c3">
        Content - right
    </div>
    <div class="mobile-12 desktop-12 column c1">
        Content bottom
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    .row {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap; /* Allow multi-line */
    }
    .column {
        flex-grow: 0; /* Prevents column from auto growing */
        flex-shrink: 0; /* Prevents column from auto shrinking */
    }
    .mobile-12 {
        flex-basis: 100%;
    }
    .desktop-8 {
        flex-basis: 66.66666%;
    }
    .desktop-4 {
        flex-basis: 33.33333%;
    }
    .c1 { background-color: grey; }
    .c2 { background-color: purple; }
    .c3 { background-color: green; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use only CSS creating a grid layout, javascript is not necessary: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

This is an example of what you could do:

```css
.grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "header header"
    "content right"
    "footer footer"
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  
}
.content {
  grid-area: content;
  background-color: #995595;
}
.right {
  grid-area: right;
  background-color: #559959;
}
.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}

.header, .footer{
  min-height: 50px;
  background-color: #ccc; 
}

.grid > * {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
 <div class="header">
   Content top
 </div>
 <div class="content">
   Content - main
   <br /> <br />
   Content - main
   <br /> <br />
   Content - main
   <br /> <br />
   Content - main
   <br /> <br />
   Content - main
 </div>
 <div class="right">
   Content - right
 </div>
 <div class="footer">
   Content bottom
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: for the one who care about css work crossover browser, it's not the safest choice because it won't work in IE

Comment: @LuuHoangBac this link says IE also supports with `-ms-` https://caniuse.com/#search=grid